# Can a batch file execute commands within a python shell?

Tags: python, batch-file

Can I use a batch file to start a python shell and execute commands? I know that

```
python
```

will start a python shell, but a batch file containing

```
python
1+1
```

will first run python, and then only when you quit python will it attempt to run 1+1. It will not execute any commands within the python shell.

Comment: You can run a specific program (file) from batch, but I'm not sure about command-line execution.

Comment: Yep. One really ugly way to do this might be to write a .py file and then run it. I'm hoping someone comes up with something better than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little searching around, I managed to find [this website](http://halotis.com/2009/08/21/running-python-code-in-windows-batch-file-trick/) that has a method to do this. As you will see on the website, all you need to do is:

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && python -x "%~f0" %* & exit /b !ERRORLEVEL! 
#start python code here 
print "hello world"
```

This didn't work for me, however I thought it might help.

I haven't been able to find any other source that says it's possible.

Just thought of something else that I haven't tested. I combined Bear's answer and mine.

```
@for /f "skip=1 delims=" %i in (%0) do @python -c "%i"
#Start Python here.
```

However, the other method should be used.

Comment: Hey @Prof Pickle, I think it didn't work for you because of the `-x` flag. It causes the interpreter to skip the first line of the program to allow for non unix #! to be ignored. So without knowing more than what you posted I would assume that `print "hello world"` was just skipped as described.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has an accepted answer but you might also try the `-c` argument for the `python` command. `python -c "print(1+1)"` will print "2" to the console. The `-c` flag means "command" and is interpreted by python immediately.

Comment: Thanks! That's beautifully simple.

Comment: You are welcome, I am not sure how much you need to do, but you can use semi-colons to chain statements together in the command string as well.

Comment: Yep. But it's awkward to put them all on one line.

Comment: True, I don't recommend writing whole programs that way but for some things it works perfectly. It is there for those simple situations where you just want to run something right away.